# Google Sheets QUERY: Passing Cell Data in SQL string literal. ( WHERE [Cell data] Contains [Cell Data] )

Tags: google-sheets

I am making an automated roster selector called "Bathroom Tracker" in Google sheets.

I have one sheet "Master Sheet" with a matrix of Student names (Anonymized), T/F check Boxes, and their schedule. Columns are the class period, Cell data is the teacher (Anonymized).

[Master Sheet Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R2QE.png)

I have a second sheet, "Filtered Sheet", where two drop downs are used to search for Teacher X's students in Y period.

[Filtered Sheet Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RV7y.png)

Here is a link to a dummy data version: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yy8F849TXrXvGsvWyeOuslsxTidNL60CFToQJrq0UEk/edit?usp=sharing

I am using the QUERY function, asking for it to select a range of columns if the cell data at [period] contains [teacher].

Here is the current cell function:
=QUERY({'Master Sheet'!B3:V184}, "SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12 WHERE '"&T(C3)&"' CONTAINS '"&T(B3)&"'   ")

If I replace the [Period] dropdown with the text "Col13", I get a working example:
[Working Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSz5f.png)

...But replacing the text in the period dropdown with data like "Col13" does not produce the same effect.

Any help in this would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: *Mr.A* seems to be listed only under *Advisory* and not *1st*?! Can you ***manually*** enter the expected output in your test sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create as list based on `QUERY` that relies on two dropdown values:

- Teacher name
- Class Name

Your formula is:

`=QUERY({'Master Sheet'!B3:V184}, "SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12 WHERE '"&T(C3)&"' CONTAINS '"&T(B3)&"' ")`

---

The main problem with the formula is that `"&T(C3)&"'` (which returns a class name) should return a column number

**Answer**

Step1:

- Create a reference range for the Class names, and include the relevant "Column number" in an adjacent cell
- Create a similar reference list for teacher names
- try this formula:
  `=query({'Master Sheet'!B3:V184}, "SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12 WHERE  Col"&join("",vlookup(C3,assumptions!$A$3:$B$11,2,0))&" contains '"&B3&"' ",0)`

---

**Logic**

- `WHERE  Col"&join("",vlookup(C3,assumptions!$A$3:$B$11,2,0))&"`

  - `C3` is the DropDown value for the Class
  - `assumptions!$A$3:$B$11` is the Data Validation range with the relevant column number in an adjacent cell.
  - `vlookup` takens the value in Cell `C3` and returns the columns number
  - `Col"&join(...` returns  a string value "Col13", or whatever class was selected.
- `contains '"&B3&"'`

  - `B3` returns the Teacher name

---

**Assumptions**

[image: assumptions]

**Results**

[image: results]